# PEM Conversion (PKCS7) to DER - AKA Base64 C++ Problems

Tags: c++, openssl, base64, pem, pkcs#7

I've just finished up writing some OpenSSL/PKCS7 digital signature code and now have a working PEM encoded PKCS7 file. So after little battle, I need to convert that PEM to DER format. This is proving tougher than I hoped.

There are some convenience methods in OpenSSL such as "PEM_write_bio_PKCS7_stream" to write your PKCS7 object. But after some extensive googling and browsing some header files, I can't seem to find anything to take a PKCS7 object and write it to anything (BIO, FILE, char*) in DER format.

So feeling defeated there, I turned to parsing out the header & footer in the PEM file and Base64 decoding the contents. As a check, I did this with Java & BouncyCastle and got exactly what I want.

Here's my code for that. With almost every Base64 decoder I try I turn something like this...

```
MIIHmwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIHjDCCB4gCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIIBrQYJKoZI
hvcNAQc ... Lots More stuff
... +8L5ad45D/7ZGJWafaSw==
```

into...

```
0\202\233   *\367\367
\240\202\2140\202\21010 +
```

Here's that code...

```
    string PKCS7String(starting_point);

    string PEM_PKCS7_HEADER("-----BEGIN PKCS7-----\n");
    string PEM_PKCS7_FOOTER("\n-----END PKCS7-----");

    string::size_type pos = 0;
    while ( (pos = PKCS7String.find(PEM_PKCS7_HEADER, pos)) != string::npos ) {
        PKCS7String.replace( pos, PEM_PKCS7_HEADER.length(), "" );
        pos++;
    }

    pos = 0;
    while ( (pos = PKCS7String.find(PEM_PKCS7_FOOTER, pos)) != string::npos ) {
        PKCS7String.replace( pos, PEM_PKCS7_FOOTER.length(), "" );
        pos++;
    }
    //Take your pick of decoders, they all do the same thing. Here's just the most recent
    auto_ptr< uint8_t > decoded = decode(PKCS7String);
    uint8_t* array = decoded.get();
    cout << array << endl;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i2d_PKCS7_fp()` and `i2d_PKCS7_bio()` from `<openssl/pkcs7.h>` will write out a `PKCS7` structure in DER format to a file stream or BIO respectively.

Answer (score 3):

A PEM file is just a Base64 encoded version of the DER file with the `-----BEGIN PKCS7-----` & `-----END PKCS7-----` header and footer lines.
So not exactly sure what you expect to see after Base64 decoding it...

As a test just:

1. package a certificate in PKCS#7 PEM format: `$ openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -out outfile.pem.p7b -certfile server.crt -outform pem`
2. package the same certificate in PKCS#7 DER format: `$ openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -out outfile.der.p7b -certfile server.crt -outform der`
3. Base64 decode the body of the PEM file (`outfile.pem.p7b`) with the decoder of your choice & compare the binary output with the DER file (`outfile.der.p7b`)

Now, I'm afraid this may be what you asked for but not what you wanted...